# AJAX search results combining if user types fast

Tags: search

sorry for not including the code but basically I am using a pretty standard function with $.ajax({url: dataType: and so on}), along with a subscriber to update as the user types. There is also some data processing before showing the results. Everything is working well, if the user types slowly lol.

If the user types quickly, posts are sent out and the results are combined instead of displaying the final and most narrow result.

If the user types slowly, each result loads and gets replaced by the new result (default behavior), which is what I am looking for regardless of how people type :-).

I know it is hard to give feedback without code, but any help is still appreciated.

Comment: I'm in mobile now but I'll will explain how i approached ,consider to first check the length of the input before do anything for avoid the first keys taps with an unnecessary ajax requests, and play with the use clearTimeout() with setTimeout() to wait  1 or two seconds until any key is pressed and then fire the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Usually the solution to this is to '[debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)' the event, or effectively just set a timeout when the user types a letter, if they type another letter before the timer has ended, then the timer gets set back to 0. This should stop the event being called so many times.

You can also cancel any previous requests when the new one is sent by using `ajax.abort()` if you assign your ajax call to a variable like so `var ajax = $.ajax();`